# Bathroom exhaust in finished attic

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-vent

I have a finished attic with bathroom where there is currently no exhaust. I am thinking of installing an exhaust fan in this space. I have following questions.

1) Can I install a fan that directly vents thought the roof?

2) What kind of exhaust fan do I need? I imagine space is tight between the finished drywall and roof boards.

3) Can this type of installation cause any moisture or ice-dam issues as the part of the insulation will have to be removed to accommodate fan? I live in the northeast.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, with the limited information you've given us, we're left to imagine, too. Please update your question with much more information about your roof construction, insulation, etc.

Comment: My apologies for not providing sufficient information. The house has sloping roof with asphalt shingles, and there is fiberglass insulation between the roof rafters.  I am no knowledgeable about roofs, but I would think there is a layer of either plywood or some other material under asphalt shingles. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please *update your question*....

Comment: There's no way you could vent out the side of the house? Going through an insulated roof would be my last choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a bathtub with shower at the exterior wall. I am not sure I could install electrical equipment on that wall.

Answer (score 1):

They do make [roof vent kits](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Broan-Roof-Vent-Kit-RVK1A/100344509) for bathroom fans. The only problem I could see if you get a lot of snow it could get covered but other than that it would be like any standard roof vent.